# Adding image in comment section of Stack Exchange sites?

Tags: support, status-completed, comments, images

I am unable to add the image which is saved in my system.

In Ask Question I can add the image but not in the comment section.

Answer (score 10):

**Comments do not support the insertion of images**.  To do that you need to be editing your question (via Ask Question or using the **edit** button beneath an existing question).

Its the same as for an answer so I'll screenshot this and circle the picture button in red.

[image]

To better understand the purpose of comments I recommend reviewing [How do comments work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work) and to understand the Picture button there is [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post) (although the interface is not quite identical to that nowadays).